# I can not include javaScript to my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

also i added css file through the function.php but its work fine

here's the code on my functions.php

```
function cp_theme_script(){
 wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/resources/bootstrap.js',array('jquery'),'',true);

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cp_theme_script');
```

Comment: Is your active theme a child theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files');
function load_javascript_files() {
    wp_register_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'resources/bootstrap', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js');
}
```

Try out this code ?